# SNAP tool not visible for QGIS 3.34.2

Tags: qgis

[image]I could not locate the sign of snap tool despite having all the default settings.
A screenshot of the interface is attached in this post.
What could have been the potential issues?

Comment: The Snap toolbar is visible, just above the layers panel, the magnet?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#snapping-and-digitizing-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on your GUI, you will be able to switch on and off different tools. The snapping is currently active and if you switch it off, then on and off, you will be able to see which icon it is.
[image]

After that ensure snapping is set accordingly, based on the layer you would like to snap to wether to a vertex, segment or area.
[image]